# how to install WordPress + php-fpm in container and nginx in anther container and connect them

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to install and config a WordPress site but without using Nginx in the same container (WordPress + PHP-fpm in container and Nginx in another container).

when the user tries to access WordPress Nginx server has to redirect him to WordPress ...

all these containers have to be built using a `docker-compose.yml`

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  nginx:
    build: nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  wordpress:
    build: wordpress/
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
  mariadb:
    build: Mariadb/
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
```

my `default.conf` file for Nginx server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;

    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    root                    /var/www/localhost/htdocs/;
    index                   index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name             _;
    client_max_body_size    32m;
    error_page              500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    autoindex off;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location = /50x.html {
            root              /var/lib/nginx/html;
    }
    location / {
        index   index.html;
    }
    location /wordpress{
              (NOTE: I DONT know what I have to write here)
    }
}
```

those containers are built on `alpine:3.12.0`

Comment: Look for "nginx FastCGI php-fpm"

Comment: Thank you, I gonna look up fo it